# UITableView automatic row height (based upon content) - still the same error

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, row, height, swift5

I want the rows in my tableview to scale dynamicly based upon the content (2 labels, total of 3 lines of text). I keep getting this error (and my cells are set to standard size):

```
[Warning] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a table view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead. Cell: <ProjectSammy.AnnotationCell: 0x106061d80; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 647.5; 414 70); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x282d09ee0>>
```

I think I've cohered to all of the requirements (as mentioned in this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902288/detected-a-case-where-constraints-ambiguously-suggest-a-height-of-zero):

I fully constrain (top and bottom anchors) the labels in my custom cell:

```
    private func configureContents() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        
        contentView.addSubviews(titleLabel, detailsLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant: 5),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailsLabel.topAnchor),
            
            detailsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor),
            detailsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            detailsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            detailsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
```

I set the rows on the TableView to automic dimension:

```
    private func configureTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .grouped)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        tableView.register(AnnotationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: AnnotationCell.reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.register(AnnotationHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: AnnotationHeaderCell.reuseIdentifier)
        
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 40
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    }
```

And I even supply an estimated row heigth in the delegate method: -NOT NEEDED1- can be done on tableview directly!

Where do I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimated row height can not be set to automatic dimension. You have to set it to a specific number try setting it to 44 which is by default the row height.

Comment: Thank you! That was part of the solution, I also added the labels directly to the cell instead of the contentView. Changed that too and all works!